Start Cmder with split terminals
If I run cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" -new_console:s from an open instance of Cmder, it works as expected.

If I put the same snippet as the startup task, it's not picked up on startup.

The setting is saved to c:\tools\Cmder\config\user-ConEmu.xml.

I've tried changing to a dummy setting just to see that it's picked up, and it is.


Any idea what's wrong?
